# Robot Framework accessing a keyword from test suite Metadata

Tags: python, metadata, robotframework

I want to set for each test inside the test suite a simple report of the computer name,
So I've created the following simple robot `__init__.robot` file:

```
*** Settings ***
Metadata        Executed At    Get Environment Variable   COMPUTERNAME
Library         OperatingSystem
```

The problem is that the `Get Environment Variable` is translated as a string instead of calling the keyword `Get Environment Variable` with the argument `COMPUTERNAME`

The log put is:
`Executed At:   Get Environment Variable COMPUTERNAME`

**Question:**
How can i call some keyword from the settings `Metadata`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about how to call a keyword in the `Metadata` setting, the answer is that you can't. What you *can* do, however, is call a keyword that sets the metadata. Within the `Metadata` setting, however, you can only define strings.

To set the metadata via a keyword is a two step process: first, call a keyword and save the return value, and then call the [Set Suite Metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Metadata) keyword. You can do this in a Suite Setup by creating a custom keyword:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite setup    Initialize Metadata

*** Keywords ***
Initialize Metadata
    ${data}=  Get environment variable   COMPUTERNAME
    Set suite metadata    Executed At    ${data}
```

If your real problem is simply that you want to set metadata based on an environment variable, use the [environment variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#environment-variable):

```
*** Settings ***
Metadata    %{COMPUTERNAME}
```